# Use Django Admin Widgets on any given page

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

This is not a duplicate! Alle the older questions either do not work, or are simply outdated.

According to the Django documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/media/

> The Django Admin application defines a number of customized widgets
> for calendars, filtered selections, and so on. These widgets define
> asset requirements, and the Django Admin uses the custom widgets in
> place of the Django defaults. The Admin templates will only include
> those files that are required to render the widgets on **any given
> page**.
>
> If you like the widgets that the Django Admin application uses, feel
> free to use them in your own application! They’re all stored in
> django.contrib.admin.widgets.

Here is my forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminDateWidget, AdminTimeWidget
from .models import Category, Event


class AntragForm(forms.Form):
    user = forms.CharField()
    day = forms.DateField(widget=AdminDateWidget(), label="Datum", required=True)
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Category.objects.all()
    )
    start_time = forms.TimeField(widget=AdminTimeWidget(), label="Start", required=False)
    end_time = forms.TimeField(widget=AdminTimeWidget(), label="Ende", required=False)
    whole_day = forms.BooleanField(label="Ganztag", required=False)
    private = forms.BooleanField(label="Privat", required=False)
    whole_week = forms.BooleanField(label="Ganze Woche", required=False)
    summary = forms.CharField(label="Grund", required=False)
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, label="Beschreibung", required=False)
```

and here's the part of the template:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    {{ form.day|as_crispy_field}}
  </div>
</div>
```

I also tried without crispy-fields, but it doesn't render either, so that's not the problem.
It simply doesn't render the widgets. There is not error message either in the frontend. And yes, the widgets work correctly in Django Admin.

[image]

Anybody a idea to get this working in 2021?